# Corretor ortográfico em português - Alternativa ao Webspellchecker

Tags: ckeditor

Recentemente o webspellchecker deixou de oferecer o corretor ortográfico em português gratuitamente. Gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem uma alternativa gratuita para este plugin. Já tentei o NanoSpell, mas ele tbm não oferece gratuitamente para este idioma.

Grata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma opção gratuita que é utilizar a correção nativa do navegador.

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_spellcheck):

> By default, browser native spell check functionality is disabled in the editor. Use the CKEDITOR.config.disableNativeSpellChecker configuration option to enable it:
>
> config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;

*"Por padrão, a funcionalidade de correção nativa do navegador é desabilitada no editor. Utilize a opção de configuração `CKEDITOR.config.disableNativespellChecker` para habilitá-la, da seguinte forma:* [segue o código na citação em inglês acima]".

Como os principais navegadores atuais possuem suas próprias funcionalidades, acredito que essa forma seja melhor do que qualquer plugin. Nada jamais será mais *cross-browser* do que deixar o próprio navegador fazer a correção.

Comment: Obrigada, Renan. Atendeu perfeitamente.